how to remove slide guide drawer
I have a multi drawer steel cabinet and would like to remove the drawers for transportation. I am not able to figure out how to remove the drawers. I checked out a few youtube videos but those does not seem to be applicable to my case. Appreciate if you can help. I have attached a pictures- the cabinet front view and some views of the slider. I dont have details on the make/model of the cabinet [image of the cabinet and slider views
cabinet image with views of slider

pull it forward, then lift it and pull more

Focus on the tab on the front, as pictured. The drawer body should lift off the drawer slides.


I did look into- the tab is 'locked' in the hole. It cannot be released by hand and needs something like a flat screw driver  to open. I am afraid lift it up and back again may break the tab ?

I don't know what to say... maybe very gentle prying will release it; maybe it'll break it. Perhaps someone else will weigh in.

Aloysius- that was it ! I looked closely and the gap in the tab was sufficient to lift the draw- ie i did not have to 'force open' the tab like I initially thought. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Was a big help getting the draws out for the move.
